# how to search between currentdate's fix time and interver -10days in presto

Tags: presto

I have this query, and I would like to change it to [Presto](https://prestodb.io/) query
but I can't understand presto's date and time.

```
between to_char(CURRENT_DATE - 9,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 07:00:00' AND to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 06:59:59'
```

How do i convert this query Preso??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [date_format](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format) and [date_add](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_add) functions.

```
between date_format(date_add('day', -9, current_date), '%Y-%m-%d') || ' 07:00:00' and date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-%d') || ' 06:59:59'
```

https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html